# Design de software com classes ricas e CDI

Tags: java, cdi

Boa noite.
Eu tenho lido muito sobre arquitetura de software usando classes ricas, injeção de dependência e tal.
Segundo o que tenho lido o ideal é a classe receber no construtor as informações que precisa e receber as dependências por injeção de dependência. Mas aí que fica minha dúvida.

Se eu instanciar uma classe manualmente para passar os valores para o objeto essa classe não é instanciada pelo CDI então ele não pode resolver as dependências.

Se eu deixo a classe para ser instanciada pelo CDI não consigo passar os valores para a classe por construtor logo tenho que encher minhas classes de setters e acabar com o encapsulamento.

Eu pensei em criar uma classe que injete as dependências por reflection no construtor e fazer todos os meus beans herdarem essa classe mas sinceramente não acho a solução muito boa...

Alguém tem uma sugestão para me dar?

Comment: Olá, Jonhatan. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! A ideia é que todos os "valores" estejam declarados via CDI e você não precise passar nada manualmente. Seria bom se você incluísse na pergunta um exemplo de que valor quer passar para alguém poder dar uma resposta mais concreta.

Comment: Ok, acho que você está confundindo as coisas. Uma entidade como um `Usuario` não deve instanciado pelo CDI, pois ele é uma entidade e não um componente. Aí basicamente você cria um componente CDI, por exemplo `UsuarioRepository`, que tem um método capaz de inserir um usuário no banco, por exemplo `incluir(Usuario u)`. Aí na hora de chamar o método você injeta o `UsuarioRepository` na classe que está executando, cria um `Usuario` definindo seus atributos usando o construtor ou através de setters e chama o método `incluir` passando o usuário. Seria sobre isso sua dúvida?

Comment: Seria isso, mas ter uma classe que recebe um Usuário e executa a gravação desse na base de dados não iria expor de mais o comportamento da classe Usuario? Eu estava lendo um livro de SOLID (da casa do codigo. Muito bom por sinal) que considera essa técnica como programação estruturada, uma vez que o comportamento é definido fora do domino da classe Usuario. Fico um pouco confuso sobre como implementar isso.

Comment: Um livro falando sobre SOLID (onde S = Single Responsibility Principle) diz que a classe que mantém o estado (conjunto de atributos ou valores de uma entidade) é a mesma responsável por fazer a interface com o banco? Ou você entendeu errado ou esse livro tem um sério problema. Note que você pode ter um `Usuario` como um componente ou agente do sistema. O problema é que você não persiste o componente ou agente e sim um conjunto de atributos. Isso não é expor comportamento.

Comment: Da mesma forma, encapsular esse conjunto de atributos enquanto você acaba com código SQL ou de algum framework espalhado por todo o código não me parece uma troca muito equilibrada. Mas claro que estou fazendo suposições aqui e tudo isso pode ser simplesmente uma confusão de terminologias. Para entender melhor o problema, sugiro que edite sua pergunta e coloque os trechos relevantes do código que você tem até agora. Abraço.